# Querying a derived entity in the ObjectContext (Table-per-hierarchy)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I´m doing the [Walkthrough: Mapping Inheritance - Table-per-Hierarchy (Entity Data Model Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716683.aspx).

This is the model:

[image: Entities Data Model]

The entities Instructor and Student are derived types with the BaseType Person.

The problem is: How can I query the Instructor and Student entities directly in LINQ if they are not visible in ObjectContext?

I was expecting to do somenthig like this:

> var result = from student in ctx.Students select student;

The derived entities seems to exist only as entities (EntityObject) and not as ObjectSet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `People` property on the [`ObjectContext` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) that is generated for you.  From there, you can get all the base types:

```
var allPeople = ctx.People;
```

Or, if you want a specific derived type, you can use the [`OfType` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) on [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), like so:

```
var students = allPeople.OfType<Student>();
var instructors = allPeople.OfType<Instructor>();
```